# Is there a way to generate blank kubernetes yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any kubectl command to bootstrap yaml file for certain object?

For example

```
kubectl generate deployment --yml
```

After which I would fill it with values I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try playing with:

```
kubectl create <resourcetype> <otheroptions> --output=yaml --dry-run
```

See:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create

for different `<resourcetype>` you could use this with.